# Docker Desktop for Windows always getting stuck on extracting

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am facing a problem with **Docker Desktop for Windows** where I am pulling the docker image `microsoft/windowsservercore` and it contains 2 layers, one around 1.16 GB and the other one around 4.07 GB. The problem I am facing is that the 4.07GB layer always gets stuck at extracting. I have tried it multiple times in last 2 days. Download easily takes around 40 minutes and extraction takes much longer, getting stuck in the middle for minutes without any progress then towards the end, it just gets stuck completely and does not proceed even if I wait for half an hour or whatever. What might be the issue, how can I debug it? Can it be due to system configuration or due to the amount of resources allocated to docker? Is it possible to allocate more resources to docker? One thing I have observed is that the PC tends to get a lot slower once the extraction gets stuck. However, when I check task manager, the CPU and memory utilization is not beyond 50%. I have 8GB of DDR3 RAM using an i5 processor running Windows 10.

```
PS C:\Users\mandeep\ringba\ringba-jenkins-setup-windows\windows-java> docker build -t windows-java:jre1.8.0_91 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1/5 : FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
latest: Pulling from microsoft/windowsservercore
3889bb8d808b: Extracting [=================================================> ] 4.027 GB/4.07 GB
6d4d50238ed1: Download complete
```

Comment: Disable antivirus

Comment: The download speed will likely have more to do with the speed of your internet connection than your machine's resources (CPU, RAM, etc.).  It is possible your AV is causing issues.  See our doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/anti-virus-optimization-for-windows-containers).  Can you download smaller images, like [microsoft/nanoserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/nanoserver/) more quickly?

Comment: Uninstalling antivirus and disabling windows defender solved the problem. My problem was not with the download. I can live with 40-45 minutes it took for download but the problem was always occurring during the extraction part.

Comment: Thanks for following up!

Comment: Also, disabling the antivirus didn't work either

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and came across this issue [Docker can hang indefinitely waiting for a nonexistant process to pull an image.](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12823#issuecomment-128311007) on the moby repo.

The suggested workaround is:

> Restarting docker daemon solves the issue

It did the trick for me too.

Answer (score 4):

Restarted Docker Desktop. Now working fine..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, check you are downloading an image that matches the current docker for windows container type.  You may need to switch to using linux containers or vice-versa.

Switching from Windows to Linux containers fixed this issue for me when trying to pull microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue.Restarted my machine and then Docker Desktop.Worked on Day 2.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to shutdown the WSL2 Linux. I ran this command:

wsl --terminate Ubuntu-20.04

You may need to run this command to see what WSL2 instances are running:

wsl --list